# How I can increase size of hostname from 64 to more characters in centos?

Tags: linux, centos, hostname

I want to set my centos instance hostname which is more then 64 characters

Example:

`cent07-env07-ins01-xyz23-pro-dot-1692697882-b.dev.api.mywebsite.` => 64 characters which is allow

But as per our need we have to set it like this

`cent07-env07-ins01-xyz23-pro-dot-1692697882-b.dev.api.mywebsite.com` => 67 characters

Comment: DNS has a limit per label of 2^6 characters, which is where this likely comes from (POSIX limits it to 255). So the answer is... don't do that. What are you actually trying to do? Encoding absolutely everything in one label in your hostname doesn't sound like a recipe for success.

Comment: @ChrisDown, the longest label there is only 45 characters.

Comment: @ilkkachu great observation. That, then., makes you wonder how the OP encountered an issue. I wonder whether they're trying to add the whole string (including domain) into `hostname` ...

Comment: @ilkkachu hah, you're right! their fqdn is so long that i didn't even notice the separators...

Answer (score 0):

Modify `limits.h` (change HOST_NAME_MAX from 64 to your desired length), recompile the kernel, libc, and any network related program that requires the value above.

You can find its current value on a per system basis by running:

```
$ getconf HOST_NAME_MAX
64
```

Rumour has it that there are some BSD versions out there that allow a significantly longer hostname, but what you're doing with those names doesn't look like great design.

Comment: Hi @tink, I can't find any result.

cat /usr/include/limits.h | grep HOST_NAME_MAX
or
cat /usr/include/linux/limits.h | grep HOST_NAME_MAX

Can you specify how I can make changes ?

Comment: You'll need to download the kernel sources (and libc, and any other network related program that may rely on that value) ... but as @ChrisDown pointed out in the comment above - you can't expect those names to work. Each label (the parts between dots in a FQDN) is only allowed 63 characters in DNS by standard, no matter how much you want longer ones.